# Rails 4 UUID as ID with default value

Tags: postgresql-9.2, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4 and PostgreSQL, is it possible to create a table with a primary key that is a UUID without using SQL directly?  Right now, I resort to:

```
c = ActiveRecord::Base.connection                                                                                                   
c.execute 'CREATE TABLE revisions (id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4());'
```

I know this is not portable and has performance implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an older question, but support for using a UUID as a primary id is baked into Rails 4 a little better now. See [this post](http://labria.github.io/2013/04/28/rails-4-postgres-uuid-pk-guide/) for more info.

Comment: I just build a sizable API and decided to use this uuid implementation. At this point I'm not sure what the benefit is besides the thrill of trying something new. Repeatedly, I've found ActiveRecord queries not working as expected. I had to overwrite #delete on a join model, for example, and write custom SQL for all association methods which crossed a join.